# JQuery Hover Attribute in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Can somebody please give a work around (preferred to be cross-browser) for the following jquery code that fails under internet explorer 8:

`var selected = $("#SomeDivElementId :hover");`

It is just a div with a nested table in html but it throws the exception:

`Object does not support this property or method`

The code works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Maybe I should have been more specific. The `$("#SomeDivElementId :hover");` call is expected to return a jQuery object of the element in the div that was hovered on since afterwards I do something like like:

`if (selected.length > 0) ...`

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you need a space between `#SomeDivElementId` and `:hover`?

Comment: In the documentation of jquery, I can't find ":hover" like a selector string.

Comment: Yes Spudley, the space is necessary as far as I know. Without it, the code doesn't work under any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard hover() function which takes two callback methods :

```
var selected = false
$("#SomeDivElementId").hover(function(){selected=true},function(){selected=false})
```